# Require assistance with GUI on Java, struggling to create panels and fill them with unique data using a MC Access database when data is added

Tags: java, ms-access, user-interface

I'm currently completing a final assessment for my Grade 12 year and need some assistance with my Java GUI. It is essentially a cooking programme, with fields such as DishName, DishType, etc.I have linked a my Microsoft Access database to my Java project and have it fully functional.

1)I am struggling with my next idea to **create a specific number of panels dependant on how many Dishes of that Type there are**. On each of these panels a unique DishName, and corresponding Servings and CookTime need to be displayed. When a user 'favourites' a dish a panel in the Favourites Screen needs to be created and display all of the Favourited Dishes. Similarly if a admin adds a dish to the database, it needs to be reflected in a panel with the correct data in the Java GUI.

Thank you![enter image description here][1]

The components on one panel are as follows:
lblDishname(label)
lblServings(label)
lblTime(label)
lblCuisineType(label)
lblFavourite(a label that when clicked adds this dish to the favourites table in the db, NB I have the adding of selected dishes to the favourite tbl on the db and GUI working)
Scroll Panel

2. For each of my dishes I would like to include a image preview of it. As seen in the attached image within the white box. What would be the best way to get an image fitted into the box?

Below is an image of the GUI specified.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkZPu.png

Comment: I'd probably go with [something like this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) Their example is a little ugly but it's already pretty close to what you're looking to achieve

Comment: You don't need seperate panels for each dish.  Create a single panel which knows how to display a dish and then assign the disk you're viewing to it, the UI would then update based on it.  Updating the UI based on database changes is more difficult and you're probably best to just have a refresh button.  I would consider using things like `JTable` and/or `JList` to display listings of the dishes presenting only limited information, through which the user can drill into to get more details

Comment: See [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).  `JList` itself is not editable, so you could use a single column `JTable` instead